# Как удалить первую строку из текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть одна большая строка в формате str

```
"Какой-то текст 1
Какой-то текст 2
Какой-то текст 3
Какой-то текст 4
и тд"
```

Как удалить первую строку в строке?

Comment: Читаю ответы и возникает вопрос, а что же для людей значит "удалить строку из строки", если в ней нет `\n`? Это в итоге доложна получиться пустая строка?))

Answer (score 5):

Можно обрезать по первому совпадению `\n`.

```
s = """line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
etc"""

print(s.split('\n', 1)[1])
```

### Либо

Можем найти индекс первого символа переноса строки `\n`.

```
print(s[s.index('\n') + 1:])
```

Вывод (в обоих случаях):

```
line 2
line 3
line 4
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё пара вариантов, причём работающих без выкидывания исключения и тогда когда нет `'\n'` в строке:

```
s = """Какой-то текст 1
Какой-то текст 2
Какой-то текст 3
Какой-то текст 4
и тд"""

# partition создаёт кортеж: (<то, что до>, <символ>, <то, что после>)
# мы берём через [2] ту часть, которая после искомого символа
print(s.partition('\n')[2])

# слайсы работают без ошибок даже при выходе индекса за диапазон
print('\n'.join(s.split('\n')[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение через определение функции:

```
def first_row_del(string):
    return string[string.index('\n')+1::]


test = """Какой-то текст 1
Какой-то текст 2
Какой-то текст 3
Какой-то текст 4
и тд"""
print(first_row_del(test))
```

Но по сути, это повторение вышесказанного.

Answer (score 1):

Предложенные решения верны для случая с несколькими строками, но если строка по итогу будет одна, то str.index()  [метод выкинет исключение ValueError](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.index/), если такое поведение для Вас не является возможным, то можно использовать и предложенные ответы.

Иначе я советую воспользоваться str.find().

```
string = """Какой-то текст 1
Какой-то текст 2
Какой-то текст 3
Какой-то текст 4
и тд"""
idx = string.find('\n')
string = string[idx + 1:]
```

Однако, в таком случае эта строка сохранится, поскольку str.find() возвращает -1 в случае отсутствия элемента. В таком случае ещё стоит добавить проверку.

Answer (score 0):

Предпологая, что ваша большая (многострочная) строка находится в переменной `str_`, решение может быть простое:

```
str_.split("\n", 1)[1]
```

---

Тест:

```
>>> result = str_.split("\n", 1)[1]
>>> print(result)
```

> ```
> Какой-то текст 2
> Какой-то текст 3
> Какой-то текст 4
> и тд
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Метод `.split()` разделит вашу строку на 2 части — *до* первого `\n` и *после* него:

```
str_.split("\n", 1)        # 1 значит разбить только для первого \n
```

Тем получим *список этих двух частей* — выберем (применением `[1]`) только вторую часть.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете:

- *записать* вашу многострочную строку `s` *в текстовой файл,* затем
- *пропустить* одну (т.е. первую) строку этого файла и наконец
- *читать* остаток файла, получая результат.

Для этого не надо использовать реальный файл, а фантомный (только в памяти) `io.StringIO()`:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO(s)
next(f)                            # Пропустить первую строку
result = f.getvalue()              # Читать остаток файла
```